# Where should I input dbname and dbPath in RDolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

How to establish a connection with a certain database in RDolphinDB? Any suggestions on RDolphinDB usage? [Here are my dataframes].[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkbku.jpg)

Currently, my code is as follows:

```
dbConnect(conn=DolphinDB(), host="localhost",port=8848,username="admin",password-"123456")
```

I intend to connect with the table `HS_daily_basic` in the tushare database shown. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can run the sql script in dbRun, for example:

```
res_run<-dbRun(conn, "select top 100 * from loadTable('dfs://tushare','HS_daily_basic'"))
```